# Compare two excel sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

csv spreadsheets with the following data:

Sheet 1:

ID Name Address City PostalCode Phone

Sheet 2:
ID Name Address City PostalCode Phone

I would like to compare the two sheets for added rows, deleted rows, changes in a column based on ID

Do you have any recommendation on how to achieve this in excel or use a third party software?

Answer (score 1):

My usual approach is to sort by id and copy paste it into open source tool WinMerge (Windows) or Meld (Linux)

Comment: Would you mind adding links, and ideally a screenshot showing the comparison? Thanks!